# Abel's Theorem (in ODEs) in n-dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

This week, i have been reading again Boyce and Diprima's textbook on ODEs, and it makes an [informal] statement of what would be a formulation of Abel's Theorem for systems of differential equations. In order to ground the problem, consider the following notation:

\begin{align}
    \mathbf{x}(t) = (x_{1}(t),\cdots,x_{n}(t)), \text{being the state vector}\\
    \dot{\mathbf{x}}(t) = P(t)\mathbf{x}(t), \text{for a matrix }P(t)\text{, and the already defined vector}
\end{align}

Consider, also, $\mathbf{x}^{(1)},\cdots,\mathbf{x}^{(n)}$ to be a set of solutions for the equation above, then the wroskian $W[\mathbf{x}^{(1)},\cdots,\mathbf{x}^{(n)}]$ suffices the following differential equation:

\begin{align}
    \dfrac{dW}{dt} &= tr(P)W
\end{align}

Has anyone ever saw a proof of that theorem? Since it involves the derivative of a determinant, I am not sure in how to proceed to the proof.

Comment: Apply this formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi's_formula

Comment: Thank you, i think that's sufficient :).

Comment: Liouville's formual, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_formula, may be somewhat more direct.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10212/is-there-a-basis-independent-proof-of-abels-identity